# Update in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am facing issue with update in rail and below the code i am using for update.I getting parametes_id as expected.But while passing parametes_id to update_all which always coming as 0 value.How to pass parametes_id which i am getting?

```
     parametes_id=DataModel.where(parameter_name: parametername.to_s).ids

Rails.logger.debug("Parameter ID: #{parametes_id.to_s.inspect}")//Getting correct value

Group.where(ExecutionGroup_id: @execution_groupid).update_all(DataModel_id: parametes_id.to_s)
```

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: `0` in response to `update_all` means 0 records was updated. Is this correct?

Comment: please add the error message

Comment: No.Updating data model I'd as 0.i need to update parameters id which I am getting

Comment: Are `parameter_name` values unique for `DataModel` ?

Comment: Please closed the question and add the new question or you can achieve by using the many to many relationship please go through https://medium.com/@pk60905/many-to-many-relationship-in-rails-cf86e12db8b0

Answer (score -1):

[image]

The above is the working example of update all please check your id parametes_id and why you are converting your id to string. I think id should be in the integer format.

Comment: For example
"2".to_i

Comment: as per your code understanding you parametes_id should contain a single integer value

Comment: Ok sure.I will do

Comment: Getting undefined method to_i

Comment: "Threw an exception inside update() undefined method `to_i' for [2]:Array\nDid you mean?  to_s\n               to_a\n               to_h"

Comment: can please  copy the content of parametes_id

Comment: Or please try parametes_id.join.to_i

Comment: Parameter ID: [4]

Comment: Ok try these parametes_id.join.to_i

Comment: great.It is working fine.It is saving last parameters id only.I need to save all the parameters id which i am getting.for example parameter id 1 group id 8,parameter id 2,group id 8,parameter is 3, group id 8

Comment: Please approve my answer

Comment: It is simple if you are getting ids in array for example [1,2,3]
[1,2,3].each do |id| Group.where(ExecutionGroup_id: @execution_groupid).update_all(DataModel_id: id) end

Comment: What will be the use of these   example parameter id 1 group id 8,parameter id 2,group id 8,parameter is 3, group id 8
It does not make any scense

Comment: Actually update will overwrite existing data.i have column names group id and datamodelid.i need to insert all parametes id into one group id.How to implement this?

Comment: Please add another question for your problem 
You need to check your database schema
There should be change in database please add another question.

Comment: @AlexRoz I believe you have to update your post with detailed info about your data relations and about the goal you want to achieve.

Comment: Click on right click it will convert to green color below of answer votes you will see icon @AlexRoz